# How to get a list of views (profiles) in Google Analytics Data API (GA4)?

Tags: c#, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Help Needed -

In Google v3 we have API URL [https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/%7Eall/webproperties/%7Eall/profiles)

**but how to get list of views (profiles) using Google Analytics Data API (GA4) ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, GA4 does not have views. It has only accounts and web properties.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using the [Google analytics management api account summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) method.   THis method and all of the management api is designed to work with Universal analytics it does not support GA4 in any way.

What you should be looking at is the Google Analytics Admin API [accounts.list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts/list)  method.

Remember that at the time of writing this api is in Alpha and can have breaking changes in the future. Also check out the [Google cloud client libray](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet)

If you need any help with code let me know I have some i have been testing with but being that the library is in alpha im not sure its a good idea to put it here as its going to change in the future.

Comment: If I am using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list

GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accountSummaries

then it does not return google analytics 4 profiles

Comment: Can you please share code which i can use for get list of views (profiles) using Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Comment: No management API will not return profiles for ga4.   The Google analytics admin api does however try to return Universal analytics profiles and ga4 profiles. but it does it badly so i wouldn't rely on that.   I have a sample on my personal pc,  I will see if i can find it after work.  Feel free to ping me again tomrrow if i forget :)